# Get Adodb execution time

Tags: php, adodb

Is there a way for PHP adodb to report how long each query took to execute?  debug=database seems to give me everything but that.  I thank you in advance.

Comment: You could time it in your code, but I assume you want execution time on the server, if applicable?  I suspect this will depend highly on what server/driver you are using, and thus won't be available directly from ADODB.

Comment: What @Brad said about timing it in code would be my preferred option. However, if this isn't possible then have a look at the logging functionality provided by your database and enable timing of execution at that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
$start_time = microtime();
<your sql query here>
$end_time = microtime();
$elapsed_time = $end_time - $start_time;
echo $elapsed_time;
```

You can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) more about microtime().